# Cast uint8 to uint8[]

Tags: vala

In Vala, some methods require an Array of uint8's (`uint8[]`) as a parameter. For example see http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.FileStream.write

I have the following code, but no idea how to "cast" my value to an array:

```
...
uint8 some_integer = 7;
desc.write(???, 1);
...
```

In C I'd simply do:

```
 ...
uint8 some_integer = 7;
fwrite(&some_integer, 1, 1, desc);
...
```

but the Vala compiler is not amused about the &-operator. What to do?

Comment: Did you try `desc.write({some_integer}, 1);`?

Comment: Will add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array in Vala as `int[] b = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };`. Hence you should be able to create it with a single variable too as `uint8 [] some_array = {some_integer};`; in your case `desc.write({some_integer}, 1);`.

Here's a [detailed guide on Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Arrays) for further references.